# Loop a command for specific output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am creating a simple bash script, How can we wait for a specific output string and then only the script moves ahed? I tried the below but its not working

```
while  [ "$(cat abcd.txt)" != "ocid1.vnic" ]; do cat abcd.txt ;done;
```

the output has the above string in start which is common.
It can be anything like

```
ocid1.vnic-fdhvndivfudsvu
ocid1.vnic.fjufghug
ocid1.vnic=dugjfjg
```

Can someon please help me in this case :)

Comment: That should work to look at the full contents of the file, though the loop in itself doesn't modify the file, so unless you have some external process doing it, it'll loop indefinitely. But I'm not sure if you mean you want to wait until that particular string appears as part of the contents?

Comment: This _appears_ to be a duplicate of [Have Bash script wait for status message before continuing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33018)

Comment: @ilkkachu there is external process modifying the file. We just need to check if that file comes wit any string starting with "ocid1.vnic"

Answer (score 0):

To look for a line starting with `ocid1.vnic` and repeat until one appears, I'd probably use `grep` instead of doing it in the shell:

```
while ! grep -qe '^ocid1.vnic' abcd.txt; do
    sleep .1
    printf .
done
```

The condition part checks the inverted exit status of `grep`, which returns a truthy value when a match is found. I added the `sleep` to avoid busylooping on the file, and the `printf` is there just so that you can see something is happening; you can remove it safely.

This re-reads the whole file each time, so it catches the expected line even if the file gets truncated and rewritten. I'm not sure if that happens in your case, but unless the file is huge, it's probably not worth bothering to just read the new parts. If you like, you could do that with `tail -f abcd.txt` as in [Have Bash script wait for status message before continuing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33018/170373).