# Wait for perfect answer from command and then move script ahead

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am making a bash script where I need to wait for a reply from a command which matches a string; until then, we need to run the below command. Once we get it, I need to assign that reply to a variable.

The command is as below

```
/bin/oci --profile $USER compute instance list-vnics --instance-id $INSTANCEOCID | grep -oP 'ocid1.vnic[^"]+'
```

the reply will come as example

```
ocid1.vnic.oc1.ap-mumbai-1.amaaaaaakfvuezyaagala7nf53zeomzarbf2h24a2lynp7sgin7ujrkr7jla
```

Once I get this reply, I need to assign it to a variable VNIC so later in script it can be called as `echo $VNIC`

How can I do that?

Comment: Very similar issue: [Have Bash script wait for status message before continuing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33018)

Comment: @Kusalananda I already saw that post but couldn't understand anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use var=$( command ) to have the stdout output of command stored in var, so in your case:

```
VNIC=$( /bin/oci --profile $USER compute instance list-vnics --instance-id $INSTANCEOCID | grep -oP 'ocid1.vnic[^"]+' )
```

Comment: I need to execute that command & wait till I get that value. how can I loop it?

Comment: The exit code will be set by grep, since it is the last command to run. So if the command can complete without finding the string, and say you want to wait 10 seconds to check again, you can do:  'until VNIC=$( same as before... ); do sleep 10; done`

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will return with a *true* exit status when it finds at least one matching line. So here you could just do:

```
until
  VNIC=$(
    /bin/oci --profile "$USER" \
      compute instance list-vnics --instance-id "$INSTANCEOCID" |
      grep -oP 'ocid1.vnic[^"]+'
  )
do
  continue # or sleep 1 or other delay to avoid running again
           # straight away.
done
```